# Displaying Images in a loop with time delay?

Tags: android, loops, imageview, timedelay

Help needed!

I have 10 different .png files and i want to display them on my main.xml file one by one after a certain amount of delay.

The order should be: **1** --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 -->8 --> 9 --> 10 --> **1**
*(the files are located in the drawable folder and are named as android1 , android2, android3, android4...etc)*

Also i have **9 Image Buttons** on half of my display. the upper half of the display remains free and this is the place i want to place my photos.

**NOTE:** The above order should again be invoked whenever i press the back button after getting out of any one of my 9 Image Buttons.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: My question is how to display the image files in a repeat order on my screen and time delay b/w the display of each file should be 5000 milisec??

Comment: If you are able to draw an image the way you like, the next step, drawing alternating images is not that hard. You can store them, or better their paths to a list and loop over this list while waiting for a certain event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnimationDrawable may be useful for you. I enclose a link that shows how to use it. It's really simple:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: Thanks.Will try and keep u posted soon :) btw will this work if i go in and out if an ImageButton. Like if i click an image button and i press the android back button will the animation still be active and continue from where i left?